# Integrating Z-Wave into Router

Tags: usb, router

Although it is possible to add another box (Z-Wave hub)to home automation, it would be preferable to integrate Z-Wave communications functionality into a USB router.

Are there any examples or history of connecting a USB Z-wave transceiver to a USB router (preferably an RT-AC68U) for home automation purposes and bridging z-wave devices into a TCP/IP network?  It would be nice to avoid another box.

Answer (score 1):

Open router firmwares like OpenWRT have [Z-Wave support](https://openwrt.org/packages/pkgdata/openzwave), I assume that would also apply to OpenWRT derivatives like DD-WRT. I haven't tried any of this myself (and I don't have an Z-Wave hardware to try).

So yes, there are examples, but you'll have to flash your router with a new firmware.

The Broadcom chipset on the RT-AC68U has [limited compatibility](https://openwrt.org/toh/asus/rt-ac68u) with OpenWRT; read all the small print and decide if it supports everything you need.

Another option would be to get root access to the native RT-AC68U firmware, and cross-compile Z-Wave support (the native firmware is also an embedded Linux), but that can be tricky in general.